# Google Cloud console Logs Explorer timestamps unreadable

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, logging

When viewing my logs for my App Engine instance in the Google Cloud console Logs Explorer in Chrome, the timestamps are scrambled and unreadable, like:

[image: scrambled timestamps]

Is this because of an error in my configuration? How can I make the timestamps readable?

Comment: Because `CEST` is still written rightmost, it appears that the time component of the timestamps is being output over the date component. Do you have any accessibility mechanisms in use in the browser? Or other types of extension that may be causing this? Do you have an unusual zoom setting? Does this behavior extend to other browsers?

Comment: My zoom is normal, I'm not using any accessibility mechanisms that would cause this. The issue does not appear in other browsers, but it appears in Chrome and Incognito Chrome.

Comment: I have this issue on both Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04, with and without zoom.

Comment: I still have this issue and am digging through logs today so it's particularly difficult to work through.  

I submitted a feedback report in console. Those usually get to the engineering team quickly. 

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: might be the minimum font size setting in your browser.

I was seeing this issue as well in firefox. To debug further, I started firefox with a new profile (effectively with fresh settings and no extensions) by starting it via CLI `firefox --ProfileManager` and creating a new profile. In the new profile, the timestamps were nicely readable and in a smaller font.

I then inspected my font size settings in the old profile and found that I had set a minimum font size. After setting this setting to "None" in the old profile, the timestamps became readable.